Smoothest car trip
I was thinking about the trajectory of a car over time from a point $A$ to $B$ and what would be the motion that would feel most smooth for a passenger. If we consider the position as a function of time to be
$$\vec{s}(t) = \vec{s_0}+f(t/T) \Delta\vec{s}$$
Where $\vec{s_0}$ is the initial position, $T$ the total travel time and $\Delta\vec{s}$ the difference between the final position and initial position.
Then, $f(x)$ will be a function that dictates how "smooth" the car trip will be. But to more rigorously define it, its properties should be (in the interval $[0,1]$):

$f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable
$f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$
$\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}=0$ for all $n \geq 1$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ (The car is absolutely at rest in the beginning and at the end)
$f(x)$ is monotonically increasing
$f(x+1/2)-1/2$ is an odd function (it is "symmetric" with respect to the midpoint of the interval $x=1/2$)
The maximum value of $|\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}|$ is minimized (minimize the acceleration felt by the passenger)

It is "easy" to find a function that satisfies the first 5 properties. This video, for example, offers this function:
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{-1/x}}{e^{-1/x}+e^{-1/(1-x)}}$$
However, can there be a function with a smaller maximum acceleration/2nd derivative? For this particular function above, the maximum value is quite high, at $9.841$ when $x=0.218$, and, on a side note, it would provide a very bad car trip! For a 60km trip that takes 60 minutes, it would take more than 6 minutes just to reach 1km/h!
Edit: After seeing @Alex K answer, I noticed that the 1st derivative is very similar to a triangle. In fact, it seems to me to be the case that if it is indeed a triangle, the maximum 2nd derivative would be minimized and be equal to 4. So, the 2nd derivative would be 4 from 0 to 1/2 and then -4 from 1/2 to 1. This results in this function:
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
  2x^2, x\leq\frac{1}{2} \\
  -2x^2 + 4x - 1, x > \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
This function doesn't satisfy all the properties and as such is not physically realistic, but does seem to imply that the lower bound for the smallest maximum 2nd derivative of $f(x)$ is 4.

I've thought of this before! Something that probably isn't the best, but still has lower maximum acceleration is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left(x\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1\right)$.
Edit: I take that back, misread the boundary conditions.

Asking for all derivatives to be $0$ at the endpoints makes it hard to get going and stop.  I would be happy with just the first two or maybe one.  If you only insist on one you can just use the maximum acceleration until halfway and then decelerate at that rate.

There's lots of functions that can do better. For example, you can try: $$
\frac{e^\frac{-a}{x^k}}{e^\frac{-a}{x^k}+e^\frac{-a}{(1-x)^k}}
$$
By reducing $k$ below $1$ you can reduce the peak acceleration (you have to increase $a$ as well). For example, I'm including a plot of $k=0.05$ and $a=33$:

